# Jekyll installation via Bash on Windows 10

Tags: windows

Using a Windows 10 machine with build 18363 with the Windows Subsystem for Linux installed (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).

With a goal to install Jekyll, followed the steps mentioned in the [documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/windows/) (which means to use a repository from [BrightBox](https://www.brightbox.com/docs/ruby/ubuntu/), which hosts optimized versions of Ruby for Ubuntu) but found a wall when the time to update Ruby gems came.

```
gem update
```

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.5.0 directory.

[image: You don't have permissions]

Even though the documentation says so, I thought permissions could be solved with sudo, byt of course it didn't

```
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/zlib-1.1.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/zlib-1.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/zlib-1.1.0/gem_make.out
Gems updated: bigdecimal csv date etc fileutils gdbm io-console ipaddr json psych rdoc stringio strscan webrick zlib
```

This is the content in gem_mke.out file

```
current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/zlib-1.1.0/ext/zlib
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20200312-8262-tpvi49.rb extconf.rb
checking for deflateReset() in -lz... no
checking for deflateReset() in -llibz... no
checking for deflateReset() in -lzlib1... no
checking for deflateReset() in -lzlib... no
checking for deflateReset() in -lzdll... no
checking for deflateReset() in -lzlibwapi... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.5
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
        --with-zlib
        --without-zlib
        --with-libzlib
        --without-libzlib
        --with-zlib1lib
        --without-zlib1lib
        --with-zliblib
        --without-zliblib
        --with-zdlllib
        --without-zdlllib
        --with-zlibwapilib
        --without-zlibwapilib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/zlib-1.1.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

This is the content of the mkmf.log file

```
have_library: checking for deflateReset() in -lz... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.5.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/ruby2.5-KHV_pi/ruby2.5-2.5.7=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.5  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.5.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/ruby2.5-KHV_pi/ruby2.5-2.5.7=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.5 -lz  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:13:57: error: ‘deflateReset’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return !p; }
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
conftest.c:13:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10:
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.5.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/ruby2.5-KHV_pi/ruby2.5-2.5.7=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.5 -lz  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10:
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void deflateReset();
14: int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for deflateReset() in -llibz... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.5.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/ruby2.5-KHV_pi/ruby2.5-2.5.7=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.5 -llibz  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:13:57: error: ‘deflateReset’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return !p; }
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
conftest.c:13:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10:
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.5.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/ruby2.5-KHV_pi/ruby2.5-2.5.7=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.5 -llibz  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10:
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void deflateReset();
14: int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for deflateReset() in -lzlib1... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.5.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/ruby2.5-KHV_pi/ruby2.5-2.5.7=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.5 -lzlib1  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:13:57: error: ‘deflateReset’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return !p; }
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
conftest.c:13:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10:
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.5.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/ruby2.5-KHV_pi/ruby2.5-2.5.7=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.5 -lzlib1  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lzlib1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10:
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void deflateReset();
14: int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for deflateReset() in -lzlib... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.5.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/ruby2.5-KHV_pi/ruby2.5-2.5.7=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.5 -lzlib  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:13:57: error: ‘deflateReset’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return !p; }
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
conftest.c:13:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10:
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.5.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/ruby2.5-KHV_pi/ruby2.5-2.5.7=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.5 -lzlib  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lzlib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10:
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void deflateReset();
14: int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for deflateReset() in -lzdll... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.5.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/ruby2.5-KHV_pi/ruby2.5-2.5.7=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.5 -lzdll  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:13:57: error: ‘deflateReset’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return !p; }
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
conftest.c:13:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10:
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.5.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/ruby2.5-KHV_pi/ruby2.5-2.5.7=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.5 -lzdll  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lzdll
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10:
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void deflateReset();
14: int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for deflateReset() in -lzlibwapi... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.5.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/ruby2.5-KHV_pi/ruby2.5-2.5.7=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.5 -lzlibwapi  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:13:57: error: ‘deflateReset’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return !p; }
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
conftest.c:13:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10:
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))deflateReset; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.5.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/ruby2.5-KHV_pi/ruby2.5-2.5.7=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.5 -lzlibwapi  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lzlibwapi
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10:
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void deflateReset();
14: int t(void) { deflateReset(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use sudo for installing gems, you can [reinstall ruby for the local user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37956249/2421916) by compiling it from sources, but I have to admit I did not try that. My guess is that this will *not* fix the `cannot find -lzlibwapi` error that you encountered.

On my machine, I instead solved the issue by installing two missing libraries (that the second one was missing was only reported after installing the first one):

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libgdbm-dev
```

You can then continue the installation of Jekyll, but you again have to insert `sudo`:

```
sudo gem install jekyll bundler
```

Even if you use `sudo` for installing gems, you can then use Jekyll normally (i.e., without sudo).

When using jekyll, you might run into the "Operation not permitted @ apply2files" error. To prevent this, edit (or create) `/etc/wsl.conf` and add the [appropriate mount options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50856772/2421916).

Comment: Just did that but didn't solve the problem... (+1 for the effort though)